# How to improve my posts?

Tags: support

Some of my posts have been deleted.

However, I feel they are very much related to graphic design. Can you please help me reopen them? Or, perhaps, should some of them be migrated (for example, to the user experience stack exchange)? Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please first realize no one here knows you and **none** of your experiences with votes or closings are a personal attack on you. Users see 8-bit text and that's all they react to, not you as a person. In most cases, your username may not even register to anyone reading a question until much later. It is purely the text of any question that elicits responses, good or bad.

---

Just some general thoughts from me...

1. Being "related to graphic design" is really only one factor.
2. If I can Google it.. you can Google it. Asking others to find something for you is really just asking them Google for you in many instances. Users don't like it. These types of questions will get responses if a user *happens* to know the answer off the top of their head and they see value in explaining from an "experience" point of view. But beyond that, they do tend to garner close votes.
3. Idea farming is off topic. While all intentions may be good, it essentially asks for "free work". We don't do that here. Designers get paid for ideation and creation. Asking designers to "give you some ideas" for free is a bit unsavory. It is also merely asking for *opinions* on a solution to a visual problem you may be facing. See #4 below.
4. Opinion based questions aren't great. Asking things like "What's the best way to.." is not a guaranteed good question. My way may be the best for me.. but it may be the worst for someone else. "Best" is not a quantitate factor, it's an *opinion*. While, at times, more subjective opinion-based questions are left open and receive answers, in many cases they get closed. Most often, they are left open if there's a *standard everyone follows* and there really is some quantitive procedure the asker may not be aware of. This moves the question out of the opinion-based realm of "best way" and into the more educational realm of "how to". But, I do realize users don't know what they don't know. So, it can be difficult at times to know what's acceptable in this area.

- In addition, regarding the #3 and #4.... *how* would you choose a *correct* answer? You couldn't. You could only choose an answer which best aligns with your thoughts. So.. it's blind target shooting by users. There's zero way for *anyone* to choose a "correct" answer for these types of questions. This makes them poor Stack Exchange questions, in addition to being off-topic.

These points encompass *most* of your questions. They are either asking for ideas and opinions, or asking to find something. Combine this with the absence of any input in the question from you directly regarding either, and they appear to be *passing questions* asking others to put in effort because you don't want to. This outweighs whether or not they are "graphic design related". (unrelated or off-topic questions get closed far more rapidly.)

I realize, this **may not be your intention** at all. But that's how they appear to others.

If you want more favorable responses you can **show some of your own efforts**. Post images of your ideas and why you think they are inadequate. Post links to things you've found and why those are insufficient. You can edit closed questions with this in mind and they *may* get reopened.

A good idea when posting a question is use a general format in your head:

- "My problem is [something]" Or "I need to [something].
- "I've tried [something],
- "but that doesn't work because [reason].
- "So my question is.... "

I can't speak for what may or may not be allowed on any other Stack, but as the questions stand, I'm uncertain they are good questions for *any* stack. Migration doesn't guarantee better responses. What's a bad question here, may very well also be a bad question on any other stack for the *same reasons*.

I'll stress, we are **glad** you've found us here and we all *want* to help when we can. But we are imperfect people like yourself. Sometimes down/close votes get cast in haste and may be unwarranted. But if a question does eventually get closed, you can always edit it to try and improve it.

Comment: Thank you Scott. This is a great answer and I fully condone all the points you make.